# Omission of subject and verb in parallel sentence

Tags: ellipsis, parallelism

Is it correct and appropriate to omit the subject and verb in the second sentence below?

> On the top half of the left face, they injected water. On the bottom
>   half, ethanol.

Comment: It is correct, appropriate and probably even encouraged since the ability to express ideas in as few words as possible is considered to be of greater literary value.

Comment: You can, but not by using a separate sentence; instead use a comma: "On the top half of the left face they injected water, on the bottom half, ethanol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is correct and appropriate. This comma is known as a ["gapping comma"](http://www.sussex.ac.uk/informatics/punctuation/comma/gapping), whereby the comma replaces words used earlier on.

But you should use a semicolon instead of the full stop:

> On the top half of the left face, they injected water; on the bottom half, ethanol.

It is similar to the first example in the link I provided. Also have a look at the other comma types and punctuation pages on that site. It is a great resource.

Comment: It's actually just called gapping (or gapped coordination). For example, in "Kim is an engineer and Pat __ a barrister, gap represents "is", but no comma is required. Similarly, in "With Jill intent on resigning and Pat __ on following her example, we look like losing our two best designers" -- here, gap represents "intent", but no comma is required.

Comment: I forgot to say that a comma is not required if the meaning is clear without it (it states this at the bottom of the page I linked to).